# Evaluate PHP logic stored in arrays

Tags: php, arrays, operator-keyword

### Objective

I'm trying to store complex comparisons as PHP arrays.  I then want to read the array to evaluate a group of variables and return whether the statement is true or false.

### Question

How can I store complex comparisons so that they can later be read and evaluate the variables present at the time?  Is this the best way to accomplish this?  Your help is GREATLY appreciated.

### Example, English

If($source = 200 OR $source = 300) AND ($age < 10 OR $age > 60)  THAN return true
Else return false

**Notes:**
Variables can be any variable in the code, I used source and age as an example here. The nested arrays can be deeper or flatter than the example.

### Example, Code

```
$conditions = Array
(
[relation] => AND
[0] => Array
    (
        [relation] => OR
        [0] => Array
            (
                [var] => source
                [compare] => =
                [value] => 300
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [var] => source
                [compare] => =
                [value] => 300
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [relation] => OR
        [0] => Array
            (
                [var] => age
                [compare] => <
                [value] => 10
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [var] => age
                [compare] => >
                [value] => 60
            )

    )
```

)

## SOLUTION

Based on the answer by @sam-grondahl
Function can handle any nested logic you can throw at it.
Accepts regex and numeric comparisons

```
$source = '300';
$age = '60';

$input_variables = array('source' => $source, 'age' => $age);

$conditions = array(
                'relation' => 'and',
                array(
                        'relation' => 'and',
                        array(
                              'var' => 'source',
                              'compare' => 'regex',
                              'value' => '(200|300)+'
                              ),
                        array(
                              'relation' => 'OR',
                                array(
                                      'var' => 'age',
                                      'compare' => '=',
                                      'value' => '59'
                                      ),
                                array(
                                      'var' => 'age',
                                      'compare' => '=',
                                      'value' => '60'
                                      )
                                      )
                      ),
                array(
                        'relation' => 'or',
                        array(
                              'var' => 'age',
                              'compare' => '<',
                              'value' => '10'                                 
                              ),
                        array(
                              'var' => 'age',
                              'compare' => '>=',
                              'value' => '60'
                              )
                      ),
                     array(
                              'var' => 'source',
                              'compare' => '=',
                              'value' => '300'
                              ),

                );


function evaluateConditions($condArray, $varablesArray){

if(!$condArray || !is_array($condArray)){throw new Exception('Missing Conditions Input Array');}
if(!$varablesArray || !is_array($varablesArray)){throw new Exception('Missing Variables Input Array');}

//PULL VARIABLES FROM ARRAY
foreach($varablesArray as $key_var => $value_var){
    ${$key_var} = $value_var;
}


///PROCESS THE ARRAY THAT CONTAINS THE COMPARISON ARRAY
if (!$condArray['relation']){

 //FORMAT COMPARE INPUT
 $condArray['compare'] = strtoupper(trim($condArray['compare']));
 $condArray['compare'] = preg_replace('/^=$/','==',$condArray['compare']);

 ///ACCEPTED COMPARE VALUES
 $accepted_compare_array = array('=','==','===','<>','!=','!==','>','>=','<','<=','REGEX');

 //VERIFY REQUIRED FIELDS ARE PRESENT
 if(!$condArray['var']){throw new Exception('Missing var');}
 if(!$condArray['compare']){throw new Exception('Missing compare');}
 if(!$condArray['value']){throw new Exception('Missing value');}

 //VERIFY ALL VALUES
 if($condArray['compare'] != 'REGEX' && !is_numeric($condArray['value'])){throw new Exception('Value is Not Numeric');}
 if(!in_array($condArray['compare'], $accepted_compare_array)){throw new Exception('Invalid Compare Value');}
 if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*/",$condArray['var'])){throw new Exception('Invalid Var');}

 if($condArray['compare'] == 'REGEX'){
    $condArray['compare'] = preg_replace('/\//','\/',$condArray['compare']);
    $eval_str = 'if(preg_match("/'.$condArray['value'].'/i", $'.$condArray['var'].')){return 1;} else{return 0;}'; 
 }
 else{   
    $eval_str = 'if($'.$condArray['var'].' '.$condArray['compare'].' '.$condArray['value'].'){return 1;} else{return 0;}';
 }

 return eval($eval_str);

 }
else{

 $condArray['relation'] = strtoupper(trim($condArray['relation']));

 //VERIFY RELATION VALUE
 $accepted_relation_array = array('AND','OR');
 if(!in_array($condArray['relation'], $accepted_relation_array)){throw new Exception('Relation Invalid');}

 //VERIFY THAT AT LEAST TWO ARRAYS
 $array_count = 0;
 foreach($condArray as $condArray_var){
    if(is_array($condArray_var)){$array_count++;} 
 }

 if($array_count < 2){throw new Exception('Missing Comparison Array');}

 }



if (strtoupper($condArray['relation']) == 'OR') {
 unset($condArray['relation']);

 $eval_str = 'if(';
 for($i=0; $i < count($condArray); $i++){
    $eval_str .= evaluateConditions($condArray[$i], $varablesArray);
    if($i != count($condArray)-1){$eval_str .= ' || ';}  
 }   
 $eval_str .= '){return 1;}else{return 0;}';

 return eval($eval_str);

 }
 if (strtoupper($condArray['relation']) == 'AND'){
 unset($condArray['relation']);
 $eval_str = 'if(';
 for($i=0; $i < count($condArray); $i++){
    $eval_str .= evaluateConditions($condArray[$i], $varablesArray);
    if($i != count($condArray)-1){$eval_str .= ' && ';}  
 }   
 $eval_str .= '){return 1;}else{return 0;}';

 return eval($eval_str);

 }
throw new Exception('General Error Occurred');
} //end of function

/////

try {
echo evaluateConditions($conditions, $input_variables);
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: global varialbes are evil. don't use them!

Comment: maybe you can rethink your logic as there might be other way to handle your problem.

Comment: The solution is no longer using the global vars. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this would be recursion using PHP's eval() method (http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

```
static function evaluateArray($inArray)
{
  if (!$inArray['relation']) return eval($inArray['var'] + $inArray['compare'] + $inArray['value']);
  if ($inArray['relation'] == 'OR') return eval(evaluateArray($inArray[0])+'||'+evaluateArray($inArray[1]));
  if ($inArray['relation'] == 'AND') return eval(evaluateArray($inArray[0])+'&&'+evaluateArray($inArray[1]));
  return false; //could throw exception here if you wanted
}
```

This is designed to work with strings, but could be modified easily. Also, you should probably check to make sure that each subarray is properly structured, but I've left this code out.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I don't know if it will work because the $inArray[0] in the eval() could possibly be another set of nested arrays. Maybe I just have to limit the structure to one level.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the recursion :0. But it's there now so this should work for any degree of nested-ness (as long as the function stack doesn't overflow).

Comment: it looks like you have a typo in the $inArray variable (extra 'r'). There were a couple syntax issues that prevented the solution from working 100% in PHP.  However your logic is spot on! I posted my complete solution above.